# Using grep with one than one variable

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I was trying to create an automated bash script which create ACL and rules for a squid proxy.
Anyway, rules look like this: "http_access allow source destination port".
Source Destintion and port were defined in a variable earlier, this is the part of the script which sould create the new rule, or tell the user that the rule already exists.
But the grep won't get it, do I have to mention whitespaces etc. in that grep? Thanks for any advice.

```
ruleexists=$(grep "http_access allow $f_source $f_destination $f_port" /etc/squid3/conf.d/$CUSTOMER.conf)
ruler=$?

if [ "$ruler" = "1" ];then
        echo '########## NEW RULE GENERATED ##########'
        newrule=$(echo -e -n http_access allow $f_source "\t" $f_destination "\t" "\t" $f_port)
        echo $newrule
        echo '########################################'
else
        echo '######### RULE EXISTS #######'
        echo $ruleexists
        echo Nothing ToDo - Bye
        exit 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do here but can you just use `if grep -q first_pattern file && grep -q second_pattern file; then echo "rule exists`?

Comment: This is an extremely brittle solution. Have you looked into a configuration management interface like Puppet or Chef? You do *not* want to implement configuration management in Bash.

Comment: grep should check if this rule exists, if not, he will create it in $newrule, else grep should have found it and paste in into the $ruleexists.

Comment: @TomFenech what does "first_pattern".. mean? can you take my varaibles and put it into your example, all varaibles were defined in that script earlier.